# How do you pass an image to a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` in `ReactJS` and I'm trying to create a component that can take in the `background-image` as a prop. After some research, I've tried this:

```
import SpeechBubble1 from '../images/home_images/Speech 1.png';
...

const SpeechBubble = styled.div`
    background-image: url(${props => props.background});
`;

...

<SpeechBubble background={SpeechBubble1} />
```

But it doesn't work. Checking in the browser element window, I can see I'm getting an `Invalid property value` for `background-image`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I also tried doing this, which hasn't worked:

```
<SpeechBubble style={{background: `url(${SpeechBubble1})`}} />
```

Comment: did you try `const SpeechBubble1 = require('../images/home_images/Speech 1.png')` instead of an import?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including a `height` for the styled component, otherwise, it won't display anything (unless it has children that define its dimensions).

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Styled Components - Background Image]

---

**components/Container**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(${({ background }) => background});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
`;

export default Container;
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import reactbg from "./images/reactbg.png";
import Container from "./components/Container";
import GlobalStyles from "./components/GlobalStyles";
import Title from "./components/Title";

const App = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <Container background={reactbg}>
      <Title>Hello World</Title>
    </Container>
  </Fragment>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Index.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import {ProfilePic} from './NavigationElements'
import profileimg from '../../images/profileimg.jpg'

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationWrapper>
            <ProfilePic src={profileimg} alt="" />
        </NavigationWrapper>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

**NavigationElements.js**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const NavigationWrapper = styled.div`
    color: #fff;
`
export const ProfilePic = styled.img`
    width: 5vh;
    height: 3vh;
    margin: 55px;
`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use inline styling:

```
<SpeechBubble style={{background: `url(${SpeechBubble1})`}} />
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I tried this, but it results in the same error :(

Comment: Hmm, is your img url correct? Did you try removing empty space inside "Speech 1.png"?

Comment: Yeah (I actually just checked without the space too). These images have worked fine as an `img src`